# Uwsgi script is not running in crontab

Tags: cron, uwsgi

I am trying to run uwsgi script with crontab but it's not working.

here is the code i am trying to execute.

```
* * * * nohup  uwsgi --ini socialtalks/config/uwsgi.ini > /tmp/nohup.out
```

How can i achieve this. Any reference will be heplful.

Updated the script to this

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/uwsgi nohup  uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/socialtalks/config/uwsgi.ini > /tmp/nohup.out
```

still no result. cat nohup.out is blank.

```
 whereis uwsgi
uwsgi: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/uwsgi

which uwsgi
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/uwsgi
```

Here is uwsgi.ini config file.

```
/home/ubuntu/socialtalks/config
```

Comment: You'll probably need to specify the full path of uwsgi as well as the full path of the uwsgi.ini file.

Comment: @ewong  * * * * * /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/uwsgi nohup  uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/socialtalks/config/uwsgi.ini > /tmp/nohup.out    Is this the right way ??

Comment: To note, cron runs scripts in a very basic environment with basic environment variables.  This issue has bitten me several times, so you need to ensure that the paths are full-paths and not relative ones.

Comment: @ewong I have edited the question with required details. Check if it's okay or not.

Comment: why do you have an extra ```uwsgi``` in the middle of that command?  Are there any log entries?